# How to merge three dataframes based on row indices?

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, merge, row

I am trying to merge three dataframes based on their row indices. However, the on attribute will not take index as an option. Is there any better ways to merge the dataframes without having to write the row indices to each dataframe as a column?

```
from functools import reduce

dfs = [result_eu_SpeciesNameGenuine, result_ieu_SpeciesNameGenuine, result_cosine_SpeciesNameGenuine]

df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=index), dfs)

df_final
```

Comment: `df.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)`

Comment: use [pd.Dataframe.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join) which accepts a list as other:   `dfs[0].join(dfs[1:])`

Answer (score 0):

Try this using [pd.DataFrame.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join) per documentation other can be a list of dataframes:

```
dfs[0].join(dfs[1:])
```